# Change Template of ContentControl with Trigger

Tags: wpf, popup, contentcontrol

I have a Listbox containing many items. When I hover over an item I need to display a rather 'heavy' popup. I'm pretty sure that loading the popup for each item is a waste of resources so  what I'd like to have is only when I hover over the item I modify the template of the ContentControl within the item to include the Popup. This is what I have so far: (a simplified version)  (this code can be pasted into Kaxaml)

```
<Page
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  <Page.Resources> 

    <ControlTemplate x:Key="WithPopup" TargetType="ContentControl">
      <Grid>
        <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Name="Target" />
        <Popup PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=Target}" IsOpen="True" >
            <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1" Background="Pink"> 
                <TextBlock Text="I'd like this to behave like a Popup - not a tooltip!" Margin="10" /> 
            </Border> 
        </Popup> 
      </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>   
  </Page.Resources>
  <Grid Height="20" Margin="50,50,0,0" Name="ParentGrid">  
    <ContentControl>
      <TextBlock x:Name="TargetControl" Text="Hover over me!"  /> 
      <ContentControl.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
          <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, ElementName=TargetControl}" Value="True">
              <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource WithPopup}" />
            </DataTrigger>
          </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
      </ContentControl.Style>
    </ContentControl>
  </Grid>
</Page>
```

The problem is that when I try to MouseOver the Popup - it disappears (like a tooltip) because I I'm the mouse is leaving the original ControlTemplate - which causes the template with the Popup to disappear. Any ideas?
**Edit:** I have codebehind available as well to achieve this (even though I'd prefer xaml)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have what I think is (at least part of) a solution:
Instead of changing the ContentControl's Template via a Trigger, changing the Popup's 
content with the Trigger seems to work. So instead of loading a complex Popup with a large Visual Tree for each item, I load a simple Popup with no content for each item - and only fill that content when I MouseEnter the ContentControl. Like so:

```
<Page
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  <Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="popupContent" DataType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
      <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1" Background="Pink"> 
          <TextBlock Text="This is behaving like a Popup now!" Margin="10" /> 
      </Border>
    </DataTemplate>

    <ControlTemplate x:Key="WithPopup" TargetType="ContentControl">
      <Grid Name="popupGrid">
        <TextBlock Text="Hover over me!"  />
        <Popup IsOpen="True" > 
            <ContentControl Name="content" />
        </Popup> 
      </Grid>
      <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, ElementName=popupGrid}" Value="True"> 
          <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource popupContent}"  TargetName="content" />
        </DataTrigger>
      </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>

  </Page.Resources>
  <Grid Height="20" Width="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="50,50,0,0">  
    <ContentControl Template="{StaticResource WithPopup}" />
  </Grid>
</Page>
```

I'm not quite sure how to measure how much I would gain performance-wise using this method, but I think it seems to make sense. I'd still like to hear any other better ideas.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do things a little differently - try something like this:

```
<ContentControl Content="hover over me!">
    <ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock x:Name="TargetControl" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"  />
                <Popup PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=Target}" x:Name="popup">
                    <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1" Background="Pink">
                        <TextBlock Text="I'd like this to behave like a Popup - not a tooltip!" Margin="10" />
                    </Border>
                </Popup>
            </Grid>
            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, ElementName=TargetControl}" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="popup" Property="IsOpen" Value="true" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, ElementName=popup}" Value="true">
                    <Setter TargetName="popup" Property="IsOpen" Value="true" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </DataTemplate.Triggers>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
</ContentControl>
```

Comment: Hi Dean, thanks for this answer, but I was looking for a solution where I didn't have to load the popup for each item - only for the item which I mouseover. In your solution - the popups are loaded - just not visible